# Open a Java class when Jbutton is clicked

Tags: java, class

I am trying to make a program to call my second Java class that consists of music played in the background and a Jframe. The first Jframe has a PLAY button. How do I call another java class completely (with the try and catch, JFrame and such) and close my first Java class?

This is the output of my First Java class

[image: Here is my first Java Class]

Here is the code of my first Java class.

```
public class Instruction extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
void introSound(String musicLocation)
{
    try {
        File musicPath = new File (musicLocation);

        if (musicPath.exists()){
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//JButton
JButton goNextFrameBtn = new JButton("PLAY");

JFrame insFrame = new JFrame();

Instruction() {prepGUI();}

public void prepGUI(){
    insFrame.setTitle("The Phineas and Ferb MATH QUIZ");
    insFrame.setSize(1050, 670);
    insFrame.setBackground(Color.RED);
    insFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    insFrame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BG1.JPG")));
    insFrame.setResizable(false);
    insFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    insFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    insFrame.setVisible(true);

    //adding JButton
    goNextFrameBtn.setFont(new Font("Ferbtastic", Font.BOLD, 50));
    goNextFrameBtn.setBounds(850,520,150,80);
    insFrame.add(goNextFrameBtn);

    goNextFrameBtn.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == goNextFrameBtn) {
        insFrame.dispose();
        new PnFMathQuiz();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filepath = "PnF Theme Song.wav";

    Instruction musicObject = new Instruction();
    musicObject.introSound(filepath);
} }
```

Here is the code of my second Java class that I want to open with the click of the PLAY button

```
public class PnFMathQuiz extends JFrame{
void playSound(String musicLocation)
{
    try {
        File musicPath = new File (musicLocation);

        if (musicPath.exists()){
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

PnFMathQuiz() {
    prepareGUI();
}

public void prepareGUI() {
    frame.setTitle("The Phineas and Ferb MATH QUIZ");
    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BG2.JPG")));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filepath = "Quirky Worky Song.wav";

    PnFMathQuiz musicObject = new PnFMathQuiz();
    musicObject.playSound(filepath);
}  }
```

I hope you can help me with this and thank you.

Comment: The way you're calling the PnFMathQuiz() from the actionPerformed() method is already correct. In your PnFMathQuiz class, the main method is redundant, because only one main method can be run. Therefore, the stuff you do in your PnFMathQuiz main method has to be done in the sequence flow of creating the object. (e.g. After the gui has finished preparing, play the music).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you said and it worked. But now I am having new problem. When the second Jframe opens, the 2nd music starts but the 1st music is still playing. How can I make the 1st music to stop?

Comment: Any chance you could provide links to the images and sound files so that I could run it on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the second JFrame first and then dispose the current Jframe. I Removed setVisible(true) from prepareGUI of the Second JFrame. Setting visibility of the next JFrame better be a responsibility of the first JFrame.

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == goNextFrameBtn) {
        JFrame pnMathQuize = new PnFMathQuiz();
        pnMathQuize.setVisible(true); 
        insFrame.dispose();
    }
}
```

And move the things you are doing in the main method of second JFrame to the constructor like this

```
PnFMathQuiz() {
    prepareGUI();
    String filepath = "Quirky Worky Song.wav";
    this.playSound(filepath);
}

public void prepareGUI() {
    frame.setTitle("The Phineas and Ferb MATH QUIZ");
    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BG2.JPG")));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

This should work.

```
public class Instruction extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private Clip clip;

    void introSound( String musicLocation )
    {
        try
        {
            File musicPath = new File( musicLocation );

            if( musicPath.exists() )
            {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( musicPath );
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open( audioInput );
                clip.start();
                clip.loop( Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Can't find file" );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //JButton
    JButton goNextFrameBtn = new JButton( "PLAY" );

    JFrame insFrame = new JFrame();

    Instruction()
    {
        prepGUI();
    }

    public void prepGUI()
    {
        insFrame.setTitle( "The Phineas and Ferb MATH QUIZ" );
        insFrame.setSize( 1050, 670 );
        insFrame.setBackground( Color.RED );
        insFrame.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
        insFrame.setContentPane( new JLabel( new ImageIcon( "BG1.JPG" ) ) );
        insFrame.setResizable( false );
        insFrame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        insFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        insFrame.setVisible( true );

        //adding JButton
        goNextFrameBtn.setFont( new Font( "Ferbtastic", Font.BOLD, 50 ) );
        goNextFrameBtn.setBounds( 850, 520, 150, 80 );
        insFrame.add( goNextFrameBtn );

        goNextFrameBtn.addActionListener( this );
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        if( e.getSource() == goNextFrameBtn )
        {
            JFrame pnMathQuize = new PnFMathQuiz();
            pnMathQuize.setVisible( true );
            clip.stop();
            insFrame.dispose();
        }
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String filepath = "PnF Theme Song.wav";

        Instruction musicObject = new Instruction();
        musicObject.introSound( filepath );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have that in my actionListener of PLAY button on my First Java class. It only shows the Jframe of my Second Java class but the music from my first class is still playing. How can I stop the music from my first java class and start the music in my second java class when I click the PLAY button?

Comment: See my edit to the answer. Regarding the music playing, when you initially play sound in the first Jframe, keep a reference to the `Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();` Clip object you create here. This can be done by using a private filed variable in the first class. Then before calling `insFrame.dispose();` call `clip.stop();`. `clip` here is the reference you kept earlier. This will stop the music.

Comment: I try to make a `private Clip clip;` so I can call the `clip.stop();` before the `insFrame.dispose();` but unfortunately I get a bunch of errors when I do this.